# R Converting Datetime to an actual string

Tags: r, date, datetime, time

I am trying to convert a date time to an actual string. But when I use as.character(x) then it returns a value that I can't convert to a date or time.

for instance:

When I extract the data from a particular cell in the dataframe df it returns:

```
> df[1,6]
# A tibble: 1 x 1
  `PLS FFM`          
  <dttm>             
1 2019-12-14 06:47:00
```

When I try to convert it to a string it returns:

```
> (as.character(df[1,6]))
[1] "1576306020"
```

But when I try to convert the string or the datetime () to a date format it returns:

```
> as.Date(as.character(df[1,6]))
Error in charToDate(x) : 
  character string is not in a standard unambiguous format
```

I all ready searched on the internet for hours trying to find a solution, but it's seems that I either doings something wrong or I am honestly really stupid.

Can somebody help me out!?

Thanks,

JOP

Answer thanks to Ronak Shah!

After Ronak Suggested that I should convert the whole vector with format I was able to convert the formatted vector to a Date + time that I can use in my script where I make a lot of calculations with the time. I Used:

```
df$'PLS FFM' <- format(df$'PLS FFM')
df$'PLS FFM' <- as.POSIXCT(df$'PLS FFM')
```

Thanks to Ronak

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `df[1,6]` is still a tibble using `as.character` doesn't work on it. You need to pass a vector to `as.character` which can be done with

```
as.character(df$`PLS FFM`)
#OR
#as.character(df[["PLS FFM"]])
```

We can also use `format`

```
format(df$`PLS FFM`)
```

If you need a specific value from the dataframe, use

```
as.character(df$`PLS FFM`[1])
```

Comment: Like this?
format(df$`PLS FFM`, "%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S")

Comment: @J.O.P.P. Use it the same way I have used it in my answer.

Comment: Thanks! But how do I convert it back to Date (format="%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S") so I can make calculations with it?

Comment: @J.O.P.P. Do you want to convert it to date or character ? To convert it to date use `as.Date(df$\`PLS FFM\`)`

Comment: I am sorry for making it so hard on you! But yeah I'd like to convert df$'PLS FFM' to a date (YYYY/MM/DD  hh/mm/ss) so when I run my script where I do a lot of calculations with the time/date it actualy can make the calculation. 

I am trying to be as much clear as I can (sorry i am a bit  inexperienced with R)

Comment: Thanks Ronak! I've got it! After I coverted the vector by using your suggesting "format()" I was able to convert it with "as.POSIXct()" to a date and time I can work with. I'll wil edit the question with your answer!